# Prove that $bH \subseteq aH$ if and only if $a^{-1}b \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am having trouble proving the following case:

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$.  For $a,b\in G$ prove that $bH \subseteq aH$ if and only if $a^{-1}b \in H$.

Since this is an if and only if proof I setup the problem like the following:

1. Assume $bH \subseteq aH$ prove $a^{-1}b \in H$
2. Assume $a^{-1}b \in H$ prove $bH \subseteq aH$

I was trying to prove this problem by using the definitions of a group: closed, associative, inverse for each element, identity element, but I am not getting anywhere.  How would I prove this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $bH \trianglelefteq aH$? $bH$ and $aH$ are not groups in general.

Comment: By $\trianglelefteq$ I meant to denote "is a subgroup".

Comment: If $g\in G$, $gH$ might not be a group. However, $g^{-1}g = e\in H$. Your claim would imply that $gH$ is a subgroup of $gH$, but since $gH$ isn't a group, this statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PiccolMan As in Stahl's comments, the symbol $\trianglelefteq$ doesn't make sense here. The result is true if we replace it with "$\subseteq$", "$\supseteq$" or "$=$".

Comment: What is the difference between $\trianglelefteq$ and $\subseteq$?

Comment: Subgroup vs. subset. $H\subseteq G$ means that each element of $H$ is an element of $G$, but $H\trianglelefteq G$ means that $H$ and $G$ are groups, and that $H\subseteq G$.

Comment: $\subseteq$ is the correct symbol for my question.  Does that mean I wanted to prove that $bH$ is a subset of $aH$, and not $bH$ is a subgroup of $aH$?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Comment: The structure $bH$ is named coset (in this case a *left* coset of $H$) but is not necessarily a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, $gH$ need not be a group (it will be if $g\in H$, but not otherwise). We can however show the claim when you replace $\trianglelefteq$ with $\subseteq$.

Suppose that $bH\subseteq aH$. By definition, $bH = \{bh\mid h\in H\}$, and similarly for $aH$. We know that for any $h\in H$, $bh = ah'$ for some $h'\in H$, which implies $a^{-1}b h = h'$. This means $a^{-1}b = h' h^{-1}$, so $a^{-1}b\in H$.

Conversely, suppose that $a^{-1}b\in H$. As $a^{-1}b\in H$, $a^{-1}b = h$ for some $h\in H$. This implies that $b =  ah$. Multiplying on the right by any element $h'\in H$, we have $bh' = ah h'$. As an arbitrary element of $bH$ is of the form $bh'$ for some $h'\in H$, and $h h'\in H$ for all $h, h'\in H$, it follows that $bH\subseteq aH$.

Note that because $H$ is a subgroup, $a^{-1}b\in H$ if and only if $b^{-1}a = (a^{-1}b)^{-1}\in H$, so $aH\subseteq bH$ if and only if $bH\subseteq aH$, meaning that cosets are either equal or disjoint.